# Unanswered Question Statistics

Tags: discussion

Do the moderators have monthly (or, daily, yearly) statistics for the number of new questions on TCS, and what fraction of questions remain with 0 answers?

Every time I visit TCS I get a weird feeling (read: feeling) that a lot of frontpage questions are not answered at all despite the discussions in comments. My views might be wrong since I spend a lot of time on math.SE & the Q&A volumes there are quite higher.

Comment: You can find it yourself using [the search](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search?) or [the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) or [the unanswered questions page](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest). :)

Comment: The front page is the new questions so it is normal to have more unanswered questions. It is also normal to not get an answer since answering the questions here are much more difficult than on [math.se]. A more relevant comparison would be with MO. The more important factor here is that questions usually don't get more than one answer. I think on average we get less than 1.5 answers per question.

Comment: Also see [this page](http://stackexchange.com/sites): 86% percent of questions on cstheory get answered while on [math.se] 87% get answered. ps: correction, over overall average answer per questions seems to be considerably higher than [math.se]. I don't know what is the result if we take out the big-list/CW questions, but if you want you can find out by using the data explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 questions remain unanswered out of 2910, which is a little under 14%. This number seems high, but many of the questions should really have been closed (they have many negative votes).

The number of new questions varies cyclically between 4 and 6 per day, with a slight recent uptick. This is over the past 6 months.

Math.SE volumes are indeed higher: TCS is a smaller community (we have around 6500 registered users, in comparison with nearly 17,000 on [Math.SE]).